# rails How to load test fixtures before tests without rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now, I have a unit test that looks something like this:

```
class ModelTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  # fixtures are not loaded yet
  # would like to setup something here ONCE (not once for every test)
  context 'test1' do
    #fixtures are not loaded in here either
    should 'test1 test1' do
      #fixtures are only loaded in here
     end
  end
end
```

As the comments suggest, I want to setup something there ONCE (not once for every test) before all the tests run, but in order to do so, it requires the fixtures defined in `test/fixtures` folder to be loaded outside the scope of the tests and before the tests even run. Is there any way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `before(:suite)` hook. It will be called only once.

```
before(:suite) do
  #load test/fixtures here
end
```

Comment: are test fixtures already loaded in `before(:suite)`? I ask because I'm using FactoryBot to create objects that depend on fixtures being loaded in the test database beforehand. Otherwise, I'll get an error.

Comment: @temp123 You need to load the fixtures manually. They won't be loaded already.